# C# Program Listening on 0.0.0.0 but not 192.168.x.x

Tags: c#, firewall

I have a software made in C# that opens up a listener on port 5000 to listen over the network for incoming traffic. To test to make sure it is working I have a program with the following code set:

```
Int32 port = 11000;
IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.x.x")

client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(localAddr, port);
```

Per my netstat -an my listener program is listening as this:

`0.0.0.0:11000         *          LISTENING`

It is not showing listening on 192.168.X.X.

When I run the test program it gives me a socket 80004005 error saying the connection was actively refused. When I run the test program on another computer it says it does not receive a signal back and times out. When I check the firewall log it says that nothing was blocked. I even have firewall rules to allow the port and even the .exe just to make sure it gets all traffic.

I have another computer with the listening software on it and it is showing this with netstat

```
192.168.x.x:11000        *         LISTENING
0.0.0.0:11000            *         LISTENING
```

For this computer it is working fine. The test program will work without a problem.

If the firewall is not the problem as I can see through logs and the rules allow all traffic to the listening program why is it being actively refused and not talking back? And why on this machine is it not listening on the 192.168.x.x address as the working one?

Comment: There is a [List of TCP and UDP port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) which shows a few programs that use port 5000 by default - could any of them be running on the recalcitrant computer?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have also tried port 11000 and it does the same thing.

Comment: That's C# not VB.

Comment: @SezMe Sorry it was built in Visual Studio.

Comment: Is the x.x in 192.168.x.x just a place holder? Because otherwise that's not a valid IP.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I am just putting x.x. so I don't give numbers. In the code its the whole address of the computer I am pointing too.

Comment: @JukEboX You could make up numbers to avoid confusion and without giving anything away you didn't want to.  No one would be the wiser.  My 2 cents.

Comment: The 192.168.x x threw me too - and 192.168.x.x is an internal address range in any case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. The person who installed the software did not restart the system after the firewall rules and installation of the software was complete. I will be sure to hit them with a mouse fail as I asked them to do that multiple times.

Once restarted it started listening on the 192.168.x.x address and all was working.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say yet exactly what's going on, but I can suggest some things to check:

- Remember there are *two* firewalls involved: the server's firewall to limit incoming connections, and also your local machine's firewall limiting outbound connections. Make sure to check both of those; sometimes uncommon outbound ports will be blocked.
- You say netstat shows your listener using `0.0.0.0:1000`. This indicates port `1000`. So far I've seen in the question and edit history attempts connecting to ports `5000` and `11000`, but never `1000`.
- Make sure your antivirus software isn't interfering. It may see this traffic on unusual ports as indicating a virus. In fact, speedguide indicates [port 1000 has been used by trojans](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=1000) in the past.

Comment: Sorry that is a typo. I set it to 11000. Anti-Virus has no issue between the two computers as it works on the other computer. The ONLY difference between the 2 computers that are running the listening software is that the one that isn't working is Win 10 1909 and the working one is 1809. Not sure if there is a difference.